# Running a website in vs2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In Visual studio 2008, if I run a website, then the website is running in other url. But it is running perfect in visual studio 2005.When I click the Asp.net configuration setting itself, the url is redirected into someother webserver.

I don't know where  to change?

Could someone please help to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you be more precise? What is the url you would expect? What is the actual url? Is the webproject converted from visual studio 2005 to vs2008? Is it running in the webdev server or in IIS?

Comment: The debugger process is not attached with the current project. When I run the application it is running under different server.The application is converted from 2005 to 2008.  We are running under webdev server not in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but if you right click on the project in Solution Explorer, select properties and then web you can change the settings here for where the website should run. Do you mean that is running on a different port number than when you were running on VS 2005? Is this what you mean when you say it is running on a different server? You can set the port number on this properties page so it always runs on the same one.

Comment: What I meant is the application(website) is running fine is vs2005, But it is not running in vs2008. Thats my problem. When I run in vs2008 , the visual studio itself is redirected to someother web server.

Comment: Is the project configured to use a specific url then? Has this setting somehow been modified when upgrading? If you follow the right click on the project, propeties, web tab when it displayed here? Has the version running in 2005 been configured to point at one web server and the 2008 been configured to point somewhere other than you are expecting? Check both properties pages i.e. VS 2005 and VS 2008 and see what is different.